# How to render input fields based on selection after a DB query (Reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do here is load the page with an input that can be selected or unselected and the value will be predefined from a database check. So I visit the database before the render is done and I return a true/false but whenever the **true** is selected I can see that the page loads before applying the changes I required. So if a button was supposed to be disabled then it would first load as it is and then the disabling would follow. So is there a way to ensure that the render method waits on my changes or is it just the logic? I'm confused.

This here is one instance, I have 3 currently in my code..

// added this variable to state

```
this.state = {
        verificationStatus: ''
    }
```

// getStatus function

```
    await Http.post({
        url: '/api/id-status-check',
        headers: {'user': localStorage.getItem('userId')}
    })
        .then((response)=>{
            verificationStatus = response.identificationStatus

            this.setState({verificationStatus: response.identificationStatus})
```

Then I'm trying to do something like this but the class is only removed after the page loads.

```
            if (this.state.verificationStatus.toLowerCase() !== 'failed') {
                dCheck.disabled = true
                dCheck.classList.remove('btn-primary2')
```

This is my componentDidMount function where I attempt to run the same function to get the status before the initial render. And btw the logic works to produce the output but only after the page loads so I can see the button color change on load which is my concern.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getStatus().then(r => {})
}
```

Comment: it's not a good idea to change dom directly like you did , use componenet state and class name on your dcheck to react update and render it

Comment: So basically you're saying render the button with a state of enabled/disabled? I'll try to see if I can do that but I was thinking about something else just now. Hollow out the div with the button and add that to the div after the database call so I can be specific about which button is being shown (there will be about 3 buttons that could possibly be shown). Does that sound practical?

Comment: don't manipulate dom directly if you can